# A keras newbie: how to get better accuracy

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I am a keras newbie so made myself a toy problem. Here I just label some vectors according to their norm and allow a small amount of mislabelling. The task is to classify the vectors correctly. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras

# Function to create model, required for KerasClassifier
def create_model():
    # create model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=100, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
    # Compile model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model

np.random.seed(0)
M = np.random.random_sample((1000,100))

X = []
Y = []
p = 0.8
for i in range(len(M)):
    new_norm = np.linalg.norm(M[i])
    if new_norm <= 5.7:
        if np.random.random_sample() < p:
            X.append(M[i])
            Y.append(0)
        else:
            X.append(M[i])
            Y.append(1)
    elif new_norm > 5.7:
        if np.random.random_sample() < p:
            X.append(M[i])
            Y.append(1)
        else:
            X.append(M[i])
            Y.append(0)
print(len([y for y in Y if y == 0]), len([y for y in Y if y == 1]))

X = np.array(X)
Y = np.array(Y)
Y = keras.utils.to_categorical(Y)            
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33, random_state=42)

clf = KerasClassifier(build_fn=create_model, epochs=150, batch_size=10, verbose=2)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
print("Keras score ", clf.score(X_test, y_test))
```

Keras reports a score of roughly 0.5 where if it had used the norm it would have got around 0.8.  Keras also reports accuracy 1.0 in training so I am clearly doing something wrong. As in :

```
Epoch 148/150
 - 0s - loss: 0.0016 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 149/150
 - 0s - loss: 0.0015 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 150/150
 - 0s - loss: 0.0014 - acc: 1.0000
```

What should I do as the first steps to improve my keras model and training?

Comment: Training accuracy of 1.0 does NOT mean you are doing something wrong, what makes you think that?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Oh ok. I had guessed it meant I was overfitting as there is no way to get over 0.8 in a test set given the way the data is made,  Do you know how I can improve my keras model?

Comment: You should change the last dense layer (model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))) to have instead 2 units (because two classes 0/1) and change your y_train with to_categorical.

Comment: @Toyo Do you mean like this? https://bpaste.net/show/e610fa9dd8e5  That doesn't do any better sadly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on the data.
First, based on your data generation, it is unlikely that you will ever see `if new_norm <= 5.7:`.
When you generate your labels (`Y`, `Y_train` and `Y_test`), you have a clear unbalance 80%/20% so basically what you see is that your model learn to predict only one label "most" of the time which is confirmed by my test. I trained your model and got a validation accuracy of 80% (your probability for selection of the label). Then if you try the following code, you can see that the model is just saying 1 most of the time.

```
temp = clf.predict(X_test)
len(temp[temp == 1]) # 329
len(temp[temp == 0]) # 1
```

Second, your data are completely random so I don't see how the model will be able to learn anything from those.
I would suggest that you change your dataset to another one. One popular one is the [Iris Dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Iris).

Good luck.

Comment: I apologise my code was wrong. I have updated the question so that the two classes are more balanced.

Comment: Still, I think the way you generate your labels with the probability p should be avoided as there is no real well-defined difference in your data/label. You should remove that. If I do so, then generate 50000 vectors, add two or more dense layers, then I see the model is training correctly (validation accuracy of ~92% after 100 epochs).

Comment: The overlap is deliberate to make the problem non-trivial. y_pred = []
`for v in X_test:
    if np.linalg.norm(v) < 5.7:
        y_pred.append(0)
    else:
        y_pred.append(1)
y_test = [y[1] for y in y_test]
print(y_pred)
print(sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))` gives a score of 0.83 for me.